# Unable to install Great Expectations on a Databricks notebook running Python

Tags: python, databricks, great-expectations

## Summary

I'm unable to install GX on a Databricks Notebook (using Python).
As I'm stuck at the very [first step](https://docs.greatexpectations.io/docs/deployment_patterns/how_to_use_great_expectations_in_databricks/#1-install-great-expectations) of the guide, I'm unable to proceed with GX on DX. Any kind of help would be appreciated!

## Environment

I'm trying to install GX in a Databricks notebook's scope as suggested in the docs [here](https://docs.greatexpectations.io/docs/deployment_patterns/how_to_use_great_expectations_in_databricks/#1-install-great-expectations). The notebook is attached to a cluster with the following specs:

- 1 Driver, 14 GB Memory, 4 Cores
- Runtime: 11.3.x-scala2.12
- Python: 3.9.5

## Steps to reproduce

The installation step:

```
%pip install great-expectations
```

Finished with the following:

```
Can't uninstall 'nbconvert'. No files were found to uninstall.
  Attempting uninstall: notebook
    Found existing installation: notebook 6.4.5
    Not uninstalling notebook at /databricks/python3/lib/python3.9/site-packages, outside environment /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-dc5a75f8-a385-41ce-9ccc-21e19faa4b1c
    Can't uninstall 'notebook'. No files were found to uninstall.
Successfully installed altair-4.2.2 anyio-3.7.0 beautifulsoup4-4.12.2 colorama-0.4.6 exceptiongroup-1.1.1 fastjsonschema-2.17.1 great-expectations-0.16.15 importlib-metadata-6.6.0 jinja2-3.1.2 jsonpatch-1.32 jsonpointer-2.3 jupyter-client-8.2.0 jupyter-core-5.3.0 jupyter-events-0.6.3 jupyter-server-2.6.0 jupyter-server-terminals-0.4.4 makefun-1.15.1 marshmallow-3.19.0 mistune-2.0.5 nbclassic-1.0.0 nbconvert-7.4.0 nbformat-5.9.0 notebook-6.5.4 notebook-shim-0.2.3 overrides-7.3.1 python-json-logger-2.0.7 pyyaml-6.0 pyzmq-25.1.0 rfc3339-validator-0.1.4 rfc3986-validator-0.1.1 ruamel.yaml-0.17.17 ruamel.yaml.clib-0.2.7 sniffio-1.3.0 soupsieve-2.4.1 tinycss2-1.2.1 toolz-0.12.0 tornado-6.3.2 tqdm-4.65.0 traitlets-5.9.0 tzlocal-5.0.1 websocket-client-1.5.2
Python interpreter will be restarted.
```

There is also a warning attached to the cell saying:

```
Core Python package version(s) changed: The version of a core Python package, e.g., IPython or one of IPython's dependencies, changed: traitlets: 5.1.0 -> 5.9.0. Some Python notebook and PySpark features may no longer work as expected. If you see issues, you can reset the environment by detaching and re-attaching the notebook. Some notebook features may stop working as expected.
```

Next, I tried the following step, namely:

```py
import great_expectations as gx
from great_expectations.checkpoint import SimpleCheckpoint
```

which returned:

```
DynamicAssetError: Updating forward references for asset model ClipboardAsset raised TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class
```